# Can Mac OS X be used as a complete subtitute for Ubuntu?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, macbook-pro, cross-platform

I'm considering buying a MacBook Pro, and though I know that I can triple boot it (Mac OS X, Windows, Ubuntu), I really do not want to give up the ease-of-use of OS X for which Mac is so famous for. Hence, I'd really prefer it if I could duplicate the functionality of Ubuntu on OS X. I'm specifically looking for the following :

- A cmd-line based programming environment. I use tcsh almost exclusively, so wanted to know whether it could be emulated on OS X.
- OpenOffice
- Programming in C/C++ using gcc
- LaTeX editors like Kile
- Video players like VLC, which plays almost every format seamlessly
- Torrent clients like Deluge
- Setting up broadband (wired/wireless) through PPPOE interface

Also, in general, I've really enjoyed the vast majority of software available through Ubuntu Synaptic Manager. IS there any equivalent free repository for Mac ? How do I search for software that addresses a specific functionality on Mac ?

Answers, even hints or general guidance would be a great way to boost my confidence that I can duplicate all the functionality of Ubuntu without having to leave the magnificent UI of Mac OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OS X has a command line environment via the [terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Terminal) that is based on [Darwin Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system)).

There is also a version of [OpenOffice](https://www.openoffice.org/download/other.html) for OS X.

[Gcc](https://web.archive.org/web/20180207075127/http://www.tech-recipes.com:80/rx/726/mac-os-x-install-gcc-compiler/) will function on a Mac as well and is included in the XCode tools package.

There is [MacTeX](https://www.tug.org/mactex/downloading.html), a LaTEX environment for the Mac.

[VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html) functions just fine on a Mac.

There are several torrent applications for Mac, but there is a version of [Deluge](https://ports.macports.org/?search=deluge&search_by=name) you can use.

Apple's [support site](https://web.archive.org/web/20140911103704/http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2301) has steps for configuring a Mac with PPPoE.

There are a few third party repositories, such as [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) or [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) for the Mac.

Comment: Beat me by 4 mins haha

Comment: Are the third party repositories, do you mean that they are free ?

Comment: yes, they are for open source unix applications on OS X, ones that you are probably familiar with using on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

1. `tcsh` can be used in Mac OS X on the Terminal app
2. [NeoOffice](http://www.neooffice.org/neojava/en/index.php) is a substitute for Openoffice
3. gcc is available through the command line and Xcode can be used for C++ programming.
4. [MacTex](http://www.tug.org/mactex/2011/) for LaTEX
5. [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html) and Quicktime X are both good players
6. [The top 5 torrent clients for mac](http://www.zeropaid.com/news/9411/top_5_bittorrent_clients_for_mac/)
7. All networking features are integrated

Since Mac 10.6.7 there has been a Mac App Store, where you can search for many apps that have been created, you can also search for apps that work with a specific extension or even a keyword on what you want the software to do.